# create new contact with multiple phones not working on swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, contacts

I want to create new contact with multiple phones. I don't know why but my swift code creates only 1 phone number.
There are few examples related to create a new contact, so I guess my question will help others.

```
private func createNewContact(myContact : AgregarContactoViewModel) {
    let store = CNContactStore()
    let contact = CNMutableContact()

    // Name
    contact.familyName = myContact.getName()

    // Phones
    for i in (0..<myContact.getPhones().count) {
       let phone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelOther, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: myContact.getPhones()[i]))
       contact.phoneNumbers.append(phone)
    }

    // Call the controller and create new contact
    let controller = CNContactViewController(forNewContact : contact)
    controller.contactStore = store
    controller.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I wanto to push to the view controller to create a contact, I don't want to create it autommatically

Comment: @matt I've just editted the contact variable, it was a part of a function. So now I think my code is not mysterious anymore

Comment: You misunderstood me. Create new contact is not only autommatically. You can push a CNContactViewController create a new contact too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using the example code [Programming-iOS-Book-Examples](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBookNew/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.swift) written by [Matt Neuburg](https://github.com/mattneub):

Instead of

```
let phone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelOther, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: myContact.getPhones()[i]))
   contact.phoneNumbers.append(phone)
```

the solution was:

```
   contact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: "phone", value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: myContact.getPhones()[i])))
```

Thanks Matt Neuburg for your comments and  good coding!